MAP and ML for AWGN
Suppose that $X$ ~ $ N(0,\sigma^2 )$ and $W$ ~ $ N(0,\sigma^2 )$ are independent.
Now let:
$Y = X + W$
Define $R=X|Y=y$ , and $T=Y|X=x$. This essentially means respectively that $R=y-W$, and $T=x+W$.
Why is it that $T$ ~ $N(x,\sigma^2)$ but that the same cannot be said about $R$, that is , that $R$ ~ $N(y,\sigma^2)$ ?
Cheers

The identification of $X + W \mid X = x$ with $x + W$ works (in the sense that they have the same distribution) because $X$ and $W$ are independent.  But $Y$ and $W$ are not independent, so $Y + W \mid Y = y$ is quite different from $y + W$.  Essentially you're ignoring the information about $W$ you gain from learning the value of $Y$.

Your answers sounds right.
However, if I write it down I get in the first case:
$((Y)|X=x) =(X+W|X=x)= (X|X=x)+(W|X=x) =x+(W|X=x))  = x+W$ , where in the last step I used the fact that $W$ and $X$ are indeed independent(so that the conditional won't affect $W$)
But in the second case I could be saying:
$(X|Y=y) =((Y-W)|Y=y) =(Y|Y=y) - (W|Y=y) = y - (W|X+W=y) $
$= y- (W|W=y-X) = y- (y-X) = X $
This is quite weird, since I get that $X$ is independent of $Y$?
I'm sure I've done something wrong and that there is somewhere along the line an "abusive notation" error.

I don't think these kinds of manipulation make sense... the only part that "works" is saying that the conditional distribution of $X + W \mid X = x$ is the same as the distribution of $x + W$.  You can't add distributions the way you're trying to.
